# How to resolve generic property in protocol with associatedtype?

Tags: ios, swift, generics

Idea is to share the common code between `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` and their viewModels. So I have a baseCollectionsViewModel which is a generic class and looks like

```
class BaseCollectionsViewModel<T: BasicTrackDataExtractorProtocol> {
    var baseTrackResponse: T?
    ...
}
```

Now I would like to have a `BaseCollectionsView` which holds `BaseCollectionsViewModel`. Because its a `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` I cant have a common base class among them so I decided to go in the direction of protocol to work around multiple inheritance

```
protocol BaseCollectionsViewProtocol {
    associatedtype dataExtractorType: BasicTrackDataExtractorProtocol
    var viewModel: BaseCollectionsViewModel<dataExtractorType>! { get }
    //all other common properties and logic here
}
```

Finally when I try to use this protocol in my final class

```
final class TrackingTableViewModel: BaseCollectionsViewModel<TrackOrderV3> {
     
}

final class TrackingTableView: UITableView,BaseCollectionsViewProtocol {
    var viewModel: TrackingTableViewModel!
    typealias dataExtractorType = TrackOrderV3
    //other code
}
```

Compiler complains that `TrackingTableView` does not confirm to `BaseCollectionsViewProtocol` and keeps adding

```
final class TrackingTableView: UITableView,BaseCollectionsViewProtocol {
    var viewModel: BaseCollectionsViewModel<TrackOrderV3>!
    typealias dataExtractorType = TrackOrderV3
```

Is this because `BaseCollectionsViewModel<TrackOrderV3>` and `TrackingTableViewModel` are invariant? Is there anyway I can resolve this problem with `TypeErasure`?

If its not a protocol I could solve it as

```
class TestTableView<T: BasicTrackDataExtractorProtocol, U: BaseCollectionsViewModel<T>> {
    var viewModel: U!
}

class TestTrackingTableView: TestTableView<TrackOrderV3, TrackingTableViewModel> {
    func testViewModel() {
        let _ = self.viewModel.numberOfRows
    }
}
```

But the issue is now I cant say `class TestTrackingTableView: TestTableView<TrackOrderV3, TrackingTableViewModel>, UITableView` because multiple inheritance is not allowed.

P.S: Sorry for the highly confusing title, couldn't come up with a better title, will change if someone can suggest a better one :)

Comment: Is there any reason you are making TrackingTableViewModel a class? If BaseCollectionsViewModel is a generic class you should not need to subclass it. If you feel that you do need to subclass it then something is wrong with your design. Also, how do you feel you are going to benefit from making BaseCollectionsViewProtocol a protocol?

Comment: @robert-crabtree: I already have a UITableView and its own viewModel in production, I need to create a new version of it wile keeping existing tableView intact (Because of AB and phased distribution) So I have loads of code in my UITableView subclass as well as in my ViewModel. Not all of the code is reusable. Few are specific to existing screen while some new feature will also be added. So I am trying extract common code in both UITableView subclass and ViewModel to a base view and Base view model classes

Comment: Now BaseView will access only the properties and functionalities in base viewModel. So I ended up creating `BaseCollectionsViewModel` and extended specific subclasses of UITableView and UICollectionViews will provide their own custom implementations. Also DataModel in existing version of screen and newer data model will not be same (structure will be different) so you see generic `BaseCollectionsViewModel` which takes data model type as a part of generic

Comment: subclass of `BaseCollectionsViewModel` is necessary to specify actual Datamodel classes also `BaseCollectionsViewProtocol` was an attempt to separate common code in subclass of UITableView and UICollectionView into a protocol and providing default extension (implementation) I cant create subclass because of limitation on multiple inheritance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is define a protocol for your view model:

```
protocol CollectionsViewModel {
    associatedtype DataType: BasicTrackDataExtractorProtocol
    var baseTrackResponse: DataType? { get }
}
```

Then implement a generic view model class that houses all of your common logic:

```
class BaseCollectionsViewModel<T: BasicTrackDataExtractorProtocol>: CollectionsViewModel {
    typealias DataType = T
    var baseTrackResponse: T?
}
```

Rather than setting the data model as a type constraint on the view protocol set the view model as a type constraint. This will give us greater flexibility down the road.

```
protocol BaseCollectionsViewProtocol {
    associatedtype ViewModelType: CollectionsViewModel
    var viewModel: ViewModelType! { get }
}
```

Now we can implement our final classes:

```
final class TrackingTableViewModel: BaseCollectionsViewModel<TrackOrderV3> {

}

final class TrackingTableView: UITableView, BaseCollectionsViewProtocol {
    var viewModel: TrackingTableViewModel!
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, gimme sometime to check and I'll keep you posted :)

Comment: "Rather than setting the data model as a type constraint on the view protocol set the view model as a type constraint." This is an amazing idea :) I wish I could appreciate your efforts by giving you 100 upvotes :) Thank you for the help :) Though am little sad that I couldn't come up with the idea :( I was stuck on it from quite a few hours :) I am happy I have the solution at the end :) Thank you 